# Uncaught TypeError when setting up Webpack 4 in a simple Angular 6 application

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular6, webpack-4

I'm trying to integrate Webpack 4 into a very simple Angular 6 application that I built before (the Angular 6 quickstart) and, while my build succeeds (with some warnings but they're warnings about stuff that I can't really change), I get an Uncaught TypeError when the page loads that keeps anything from appearing on the screen.  I've looked at where it is coming from (my main.ts file), however I can't seem to find any reason why it may be giving me this issue and I can't find anyone who has this same issue when using Webpack 4 with Angular 6.  I'm a beginner when it comes to this and this is my first go at it so if anyone can help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

---

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at e (app.js:1)
    at Module.eval (webpack-internal:///2:271)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///2:16414)
    at Module.2 (app.js:1)
    at e (app.js:1)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///187:3)
    at Object.187 (app.js:1)
    at e (app.js:1)
    at Object.188 (app.js:1)
    at e (app.js:1)
    at 0 (app.js:1)
    at app.js:1
```

---

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev.js');
```

webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: { configFileName: helpers.root('tsconfig.json') }
                    }, 'angular2-template-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    {
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ],

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'async',
            minSize: 30000,
            minChunks: 1,
            maxAsyncRequests: 5,
            maxInitialRequests: 3,
            automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
            name: true,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    priority: -10
                },
                default: {
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If anyone needs me to post any other files, just let me know.